# Convert HEX to Decimal

Tags: vb.net, hex

Hi I get the HEX value string convert to Decimal but I get the following error 'Input string was not in the correct format'. Anyone please help. Thanks

```
'a = F1 F7 F1 F2
Dim hexValuesSplit As String() = a.Split(" ")
Dim decAgain As Integer
For Each val As String In hexValuesSplit
    decAgain = Integer.Parse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
     Console.WriteLine(decAgain)
    'Xor with F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F8
    'eg: Hex(&HF5 Xor &HF1).PadLeft(2, "0")
Next
```

Update
I change the following code and get the following error 'Index was out of range'

```
        'a = F1 F7 F1 F2

        Dim hexValuesSplit As String() = a.Split(" ")

        For Each val As String In hexValuesSplit
            Dim decAgain As Integer = 0
            decAgain = Convert.ToInt32(val, 16)
            Console.WriteLine(decAgain)
        Next
```